# Python Tkinter Loop to validate entry before INSERT SQLITE

Tags: python, sqlite, loops, tkinter

I am trying to validate an entry before inserting that information to SQLITE database.
I have a main Tkinter canvas with buttons. In this case, the button opens another window where user can input the required fields. My idea is to avoid users submitting empty fields.
I managed to have a message box to say that something was wrong but once I press "Ok" the code continues and closes the input window.
Step 1 - Open the Input Window:

```
def open_add_ship_window():
    global ship_window
    ship_window = Tk()
    ship_window.title('Add Ship')
    ship_window.iconbitmap(
        'C:/Users/eduardo.js.ramos/Desktop/VSCode/img directory/ship_icon_1.ico')
    ship_window.geometry("400x200")
    global ship_name_ship_window
    global ship_imo_ship_window
    global ISM_ship_window
    global ISM_IMO_ship_window
    # Create Text Boxes
    ship_name_ship_window = Entry(ship_window, width=40)
    ship_name_ship_window.grid(row=0, column=1, pady=(10, 0))
    ship_imo_ship_window = Entry(ship_window, width=40)
    ship_imo_ship_window.grid(row=1, column=1)
    ISM_ship_window = Entry(ship_window, width=40)
    ISM_ship_window.grid(row=2, column=1)
    ISM_IMO_ship_window = Entry(ship_window, width=40)
    ISM_IMO_ship_window.grid(row=3, column=1)
    # Create Labels
    ship_name_ship_window_label = Label(
        ship_window, text="Vessel Name")
    ship_name_ship_window_label.grid(row=0, column=0, pady=(10, 0))
    ship_imo_ship_window_label = Label(
        ship_window, text="Vessel IMO")
    ship_imo_ship_window_label.grid(row=1, column=0)
    ISM_ship_window_label = Label(ship_window, text="ISM Company")
    ISM_ship_window_label.grid(row=2, column=0)
    ISM_IMO_ship_window_label = Label(
        ship_window, text="ISM IMO Number")
    ISM_IMO_ship_window_label.grid(row=3, column=0)
    # Create Save New Ship Button
    save_ship_btn = Button(
        ship_window, text="Add New Ship", command=add_ship)
    save_ship_btn.grid(row=4, column=0, columnspan=2,
                       pady=10, padx=10, ipadx=50)
```

Step 2 - Submit the data to SQLITE database:

```
def add_ship():
    # connect to database
    conn = sqlite3.connect('PSC.sdb')
    # create cursor
    c = conn.cursor()
    while True:
        if len(ship_name_ship_window.get()) != 0 \
                or len(ship_imo_ship_window.get()) != 0 \
                or len(ISM_ship_window.get()) != 0 \
                or len(ISM_IMO_ship_window.get()) != 0:
            c.execute("INSERT INTO ships VALUES(:name, :imoship, :ism, :ismimo , null, null)",
                      {
                          'name': ship_name_ship_window.get(),
                          'imoship': ship_imo_ship_window.get(),
                          'ism': ISM_ship_window.get(),
                          'ismimo': ISM_IMO_ship_window.get()
                      })
        else:
            messagebox.showwarning(title='Review Needed', message='Please complete all fieds.')
            continue
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
    ship_window.destroy()
```

Do you guys have any suggestions?

Comment: Is this working? What is the problem? and why not use `sqlite` placeholders instead of this method of passing in values in `VALUES(:name, ........)`

Comment: I am a beginner on this and without any IT background, Trying to learn and produce something that might generate some extra income.

Comment: Im also a beginner, but you have to elaborate on your issue a little more for someone to be able to help

Comment: You should use `and` instead of `or` in the `if` statement.

Comment: I have a second tkinter window opened where I have 4 entry box and 1 button. The button INSERTS a new row in SQLITE database. If one or more entry boxes are not completed, I want the message box to pop to alert the user and bring it back to the window where he can continue to type in the remaining information

Comment: @Eduardo yes `and` seems more apt for your case

Comment: @CoolCloud and acw1668 you are correct but. Still does not solve the main issue :(

Comment: Now the only thing i can suggest is to try removing `\` in the if statements and make sure the indentation and all are correct

Comment: You should not close the input window if any entry is empty when 'OK' button is clicked.  As the posted code does not include the logic of the function which will be called when submitting the data, we cannot identify the cause of the issue.

Comment: @acw1668 Post edited with the integrity of the code.

Comment: You should move the last three lines inside `add_ship()` into the `if` block.  Of course you need to change `or` to `and` as well.  Also remove the `while` loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- you should move the last three lines inside `add_ship()` into the `if` block
- change `or` to `and` in the `if` statement
- remove the while loop

Below is the modified `add_ship()`:

```
def add_ship():
    # get the information
    ship_name = ship_name_ship_window.get().strip()
    ship_imo = ship_imo_ship_window.get().strip()
    ism_ship = ISM_ship_window.get().strip()
    ism_imo = ISM_IMO_ship_window.get().strip()
    # if all is input
    if ship_name and ship_imo and ism_ship and ism_imo:
        # connect to database
        conn = sqlite3.connect('PSC.sdb')
        # create cursor
        c = conn.cursor()
        c.execute("INSERT INTO ships VALUES (:name, :imoship, :ism, :ismimo, NULL, NULL)",
                  {
                      'name': ship_name,
                      'imoship': ship_imo,
                      'ism': ism_ship,
                      'ismimo': ism_imo
                  })
        conn.commit()
        conn.close()
        ship_window.destroy()
    else:
        messagebox.showwarning(title='Review Needed', message='Please complete all fieds.')
```

Comment: Works perfectly and solves my problem. Thank you very much for your time and patience @acw1668

Answer (score 0):

After a message box is closed the mainloop gets over so you may have to put the above code in a loop such that the loop does not end once the message box shows the error.

One potential way could be:

```
While True :
"""Input tags here"""
if len(ship_name_ship_window.get()) != 0 \
                or len(ship_imo_ship_window.get()) != 0 \
                or len(ISM_ship_window.get()) != 0 \
                or len(ISM_IMO_ship_window.get()) != 0:
            c.execute("INSERT INTO ships VALUES(:name, :imoship, :ism, :ismimo , null, null)",
                      {
                          'name': ship_name_ship_window.get(),
                          'imoship': ship_imo_ship_window.get(),
                          'ism': ISM_ship_window.get(),
                          'ismimo': ISM_IMO_ship_window.get()
                      })
            break
else:
     messagebox.showwarning(title='Review Needed', message='Please complete all fieds.')
     continue
```

Comment: _"After a message box is closed the mainloop gets over"_  the `root.mainloop()` gets over when the app is closed only.

Comment: I have tried this way but hen I keep on getting the message box over and over again!

Comment: @CoolCloud the loop that closes is not the main one but the one where I have the input boxes that were left empty.

Comment: Just put the input boxes into the loop i have made and try again

Comment: @VedantMatanhelia what do you mean by input tags? this "'name': ship_name_ship_window.get(),"?

Comment: i mean the entry tags or whatever he is using to get user input

Comment: Did it help you .